# Hibernate multi level of transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, dao, data-access-object

I have some hibernate code and I want my code run in 1 transaction
let me explain in code

```
public void changeBranch(Branch branch) throws DatabaseException {
//some code
            humanDao.update(he);
            superBranchUsername = branch.getFatherUsername();
            int superBranchId = branchDao.getBranchIdByUserName(superBranchUsername);
            BranchEntity superBranch = branchDao.load(superBranchId);
            BranchEntity be = new BranchEntity();
            setBranchEntity(be, he, pkId, bname, confirmed, level, studentCount, uname, superBranch);
            branchDao.update(be);   // update kardane jadvale Branch va Set kardane Human motenazer be on
//some code
}
```

Both  `humanDao.update(he);` and `branchDao.update(be);` run in transaction handle by My GenericDAO that humanDao and branchDao are inherited from it.
but I want this block of code (wrote above) to also run in a transaction!! How can I get to Hibernate to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find how should I fix it if I new session in  `changeBranch(Branch branch)` and pass this session as a parameter to my DAO my problem solved

Answer (score 2):

DAOs should not handle transactions for exactly the reason you've discovered: they can't know when they're part of a larger transaction.

If you were using [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) declarative transactions, you'd have a service layer that would create the transaction context for both DAOs and deal with everything.  I would recommend doing something like that.

UPDATE: I added a link to Spring.

Comment: Tanx but I don't know what is Spring declarative transactions exactly,
i must read about this method.

Comment: I'm curious - do you think it's ok for the DAO to (eagerly) flush the hibernate session when it completes it's portion of work, or should it wait for the transaction to end?

Comment: I'd wait for the transaction to end.

Answer (score 1):

Please see: [Chapter 11. Transactions and Concurrency](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/transactions.html)

Comment: I want quick Answer man , I myself know can read from this site